# How Do I compare non-array field with array in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have following documents

```
 users = [
      { name: 'kiran', age: 22, location: 'pune' },
      { name: 'rahul', age: 23, location: 'mumbai' },
      { name: 'amit', age: 25, location: 'nashik' },
      { name: 'abhijeet', age: 26, location: 'pune' }
    ]
```

I have to find users based on multiple locations, So I have input array `locations = ["pune", "nashik"]`.
It should result in three documents except one whose name is `rahul` because input array doesn't match his location.

```
output = [
      { name: 'kiran', age: 22, location: 'pune' },
      { name: 'amit', age: 25, location: 'nashik' },
      { name: 'abhijeet', age: 26, location: 'pune' }
    ]
```

So how can I achieve this with MongoDB.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator. 
If `users` are stored as sub-document, use [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KFsVs3qSCEq) approach.

```
db.users.find({
  location: {
    $in: [
      "pune",
      "nashik"
    ]
  }
})
```

---

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      location: {
        $in: [
          "pune",
          "nashik"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7BuQvl4tYD3)

**EDIT:** Nodejs code

```
let query     = [];
let locations = ['pune', 'nashik'];
query.push({
    '$match': { 'location': { '$in': locations } }                
});
const output = await Users.aggregate(query);
```

Comment: it works fine. but when I do the same thing with aggregate query it gives `MongoError: $in needs an array` Error